# How to use SSR with Redux in Next.js(Typescript) using next-redux-wrapper?

Tags: react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

Using redux with SSR in Next.js(Typescript) using next-redux-wrapper, but getting error on this line

> async ({ req, store })

Says, ***Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>): Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any; }>>***

***Property 'req' does not exist on type 'Store<EmptyObject & { filterReducer: never; }, any> & { dispatch: unknown; }'.***

***Property 'store' does not exist on type 'Store<EmptyObject & { filterReducer: never; }, any> & { dispatch: unknown; }'***

Here is my SSR code:-

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(async ({ req, store }) => {


  let { query } = req

  let searchCategory = query.category?.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-");

  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const response = await apolloClient.query({
    query: GET_PRODUCT_BY_CATEGORY,
    variables: {
      numProducts: 10,
      category: searchCategory
    }
  });
  await store.dispatch(getProducts(response));
  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `wrapper.getServerSideProps` in a wrong way.

Try like the following:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  store => async ({req, res, query}) => {
    // do your stuff with store and req
  }
);
```

If you're looking for a working demo, you can visit [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458632/11792577)

Comment: If I want to access query parameter inside it, then how can I do that?
without wrapper it is easily done by : -  {query} = context.

Comment: But  "wrapper.getServerSideProps(async ({ req, store })" is working with Javascript.

Comment: `({req, res, ...etc})` is actually `context` you're looking for. You can destructure it `({req, res, query})`. @AspDev18

Answer (score 0):

This code base could help you. ("next": "10.1.3")
Try using `getInitialProps` instead of `getServerSideProps`.
This works in my case. Like code below:

Try
in _app.js

```
import { wrapper } from '/store';

function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;
...
return (
            <Component {...pageProps} />
       )
}
App.getInitialProps = async props => {
  const { Component, ctx } = props;
  const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
    ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    : {};
  //Anything returned here can be accessed by the client
  return { pageProps: pageProps, store: ctx.store };
};
export default wrapper.withRedux(App);
```

store.js file:

```
const makeStore = props => {
  if (!isEmpty(props)) {
    return createStore(reducer, bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware]));
  } else {
    const { persistStore, persistReducer } = require('redux-persist');
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
    };
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer); // Create a new reducer with our existing reducer
    const store = createStore(
      persistedReducer,
      bindMiddleware([thunkMiddleware])
    ); // Creating the store again

    store.__persistor = persistStore(store); // This creates a persistor object & push that persisted object to .__persistor, so that we can avail the persistability feature
    return store;
  }
};

// Export the wrapper & wrap the pages/_app.js with this wrapper only
export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);
```

in your page:

```
HomePage.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
   const { store, query, res } = ctx;
};
```