# Redux toolkit typescript type issue with next js and next-redux-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bizsur-x5en9y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore.ts)

I follow the setup of redux toolkit for next js in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426965/how-to-use-next-redux-wrapper-with-next-js-redux-toolkit-and-typescript-p/70458621). However, in the original question's `tsconfig.json`, `compilerOptions.strict = false` while mine is `true`. The issue I got is in `store.js`. If you look at the demo, when calling `configureStore`, the reducer has the following issue:

```
Type '(state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => any' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ counter: CounterState; kanyeQuote: KanyeState; }>, AnyAction> | ReducersMapObject<CombinedState<{ counter: CounterState; kanyeQuote: KanyeState; }>, AnyAction>'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `reducer` definition to

```
const reducer: typeof combinedReducer = (state, action) => {
```

then it will work just fine.

Comment: I just did it but still got some type error `Type '(state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>, action: AnyAction) => any' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ counter: CounterState; kanyeQuote: KanyeState; }>, AnyAction>'.` I apply the change in the same stackblitz demo link.

Comment: Yes, because you added types to `state` and `action` which I explicitly removed.