# next-redux-wrapper Generic type 'MakeStore' requires 1 type argument(s) in configureStore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next-redux-wrapper

Error on MakeStore saying Generic type 'MakeStore' requires 1 type argument(s) .ts(2314)

configureStore.ts is the following:

```
import {
  configureStore,
  EnhancedStore,
  getDefaultMiddleware,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { MakeStore } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { Env } from '../constants';
import { rootReducer, RootState } from './reducers';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()
      .concat(logger),
  devTools: Env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});

export const makeStore: MakeStore = (_?: RootState): EnhancedStore => store;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `EnhancedStore` type.  You should *never* use that type directly, because you'll actually end up throwing away the real type information that is inferred from the call to `configureStore()` itself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. turns out it was outdated way of configuring the store. rewrote it according to the answer [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426965/how-to-use-next-redux-wrapper-with-next-js-redux-toolkit-and-typescript-p)