# Stop api call when route changes in next js. Only call api once when page loades

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page in next js. I want to call the api in "getServerSideprops" only when the page is loaded first time. Example: You visited xyz page and i want to call api on that first visit. After that if you switched to any other page and came back to this xyz page.. I want to check in my redux if i already have data for this page.. i don't want to call the api again.

[Here is the code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gju6C.png)

Comment: If you want to avoid making unnecessary calls when using SSR, you should look into caching the response you get from `getServerSideProps`. See [How to enable cache for getServerSideProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333002/how-to-enable-cache-for-getserversideprops).

Answer (score 0):

Server-side rendering is great to fetch data that changes on every render. Here it seems to me like your data doesn't change that often. The best solution imo would be to use incremental static regeneration. Generating a static page with revalidate every minute for exemple.

Read more at: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

```js
// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It may be called again, on a serverless function, if
// revalidation is enabled and a new request comes in
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await apiCall('route', 'get', null)

  return {
    props: {
      data: response.data ?? null
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every 10 seconds
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
}
```

You may also want to set caching headers. Example below. Read more at: https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching

```js
// This value is considered fresh for ten seconds (s-maxage=10).
// If a request is repeated within the next 10 seconds, the previously
// cached value will still be fresh. If the request is repeated before 59 seconds,
// the cached value will be stale but still render (stale-while-revalidate=59).
//
// In the background, a revalidation request will be made to populate the cache
// with a fresh value. If you refresh the page, you will see the new value.
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  const response = await apiCall('route', 'get', null)

  res.setHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59'
  )

  return {
    props: {
      data: response.data ?? null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pnxdxt, The user have to refresh the page twice in order to see the updated content.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using redux, you will have to make use of a library called [next-redux-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-redux-wrapper). The way you will accomplish your goal is, once you fetch your data, you will store this data in the server instance of redux and from there on, you can check every time before this request is made, if that particular data already exists in the store. You can learn more about this in the [ReadMe](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper#getserversideprops) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70426965/how-to-use-next-redux-wrapper-with-next-js-redux-toolkit-and-typescript-p)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `shallow: true` that will skip the getServerSideProp() call after the initial call. [shallow-routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing)

Comment: Shahroon, I appreciate your answer but the shallow routing will only work if the url is same. I want to skip the api calls when user is switching between multiple routes.

Comment: Yes, it seems like there's no support to skip getServerSideProp() on navigation, there is open PR (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/23921) where some contributors share some hacks to achieve desired result.